# FindControl returns null text object

Tags: c#, asp.net, gridview

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="Default.aspx.cs" Inherits="BindGridView._Default" %>

<!DOCTYPE html PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD XHTML 1.0 Transitional//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/xhtml1/DTD/xhtml1-transitional.dtd">
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml">
<head runat="server">
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <form id="form1" runat="server">
    <div>
        <asp:GridView ID="GridView1" runat="server" AutoGenerateColumns="false" OnRowEditing="OnRowEditing"
            OnRowCommand="GridView1_RowCommand" OnRowDataBound="GridView1_RowDataBound" OnRowUpdating="GridView1_RowUpdating">

            <Columns>
                <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name1">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name1")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUName1" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name1")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name2" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name2")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUName2" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name2")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                  <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Name3" >
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblName3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name3")%>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:TextBox ID="txtUName3" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Name3")%>' />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField HeaderText="Country">
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:Label ID="lblCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country")%>' />                       
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                     <asp:HiddenField ID="hdnCountry" runat="server" Value='<%#Eval("country") %>' />
                       <%-- <asp:TextBox ID="txtCountry" runat="server" Text='<%# Eval("Country")%>' />--%>
                        <asp:DropDownList ID="DrpDownList1" runat="server" >
                        <asp:ListItem>India</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>United States</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>France</asp:ListItem>
                        <asp:ListItem>Russia</asp:ListItem>
                        </asp:DropDownList>
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>

                 <asp:TemplateField>
                    <ItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton1" Text="Edit" runat="server" CommandName="Edit" CommandArgument='<%# DataBinder.Eval(Container.DataItem, "Id") %>' />
                    </ItemTemplate>
                    <EditItemTemplate>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton2" Text="Update" runat="server" CommandName="Update"/>
                        <asp:LinkButton ID="LinkButton3" Text="Cancel" runat="server" OnClick="OnCancel" />
                    </EditItemTemplate>
                </asp:TemplateField>               
            </Columns>
        </asp:GridView>
    </div>
    </form>
</body>
</html>
```

**Front End**

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Web;
using System.Web.UI;
using System.Web.UI.WebControls;
using System.Data;

namespace BindGridView
{
    public partial class _Default : System.Web.UI.Page
    {
        public List<Employee> lstEmp = new List<Employee>();
        protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (!this.IsPostBack)
            {

                BindGrid();
            }

        }

        protected void BindGrid()
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmp = ReturnList();
            GridView1.DataSource = lstEmp;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void OnRowEditing(object sender, GridViewEditEventArgs e)
        {        
            GridView1.EditIndex = 0;
            BindEdit(Session["Name"].ToString());
        }

        protected void OnCancel(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            GridView1.EditIndex = -1;
            this.BindGrid();
        }

        private void BindEdit(string id)
        {
            List<Employee> lstEmp = ReturnList();
            lstEmp = new List<Employee>(lstEmp.Where(x => x.Id.ToString() == id).ToList());

            GridView1.DataSource = lstEmp;
            GridView1.DataBind();
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowCommand(object sender, GridViewCommandEventArgs e)
        { 
            try
            {
                if (e.CommandName == "Edit")//redirect to MangeRulepage and set query string Mode variable to 'EDIT'
                {
                    //BindEdit(e.CommandArgument.ToString());
                    Session["Name"] = e.CommandArgument.ToString();
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                throw ex;
            }     
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowDataBound(object sender, GridViewRowEventArgs e)
        {
            if (e.Row.RowType == DataControlRowType.DataRow && GridView1.EditIndex == e.Row.RowIndex)
            {
                DropDownList ddl = (DropDownList)e.Row.FindControl("DrpDownList1");
                HiddenField hdnval = (HiddenField)e.Row.FindControl("hdnCountry");
                if (ddl != null)
                { 
                    ddl.Items.FindByValue(hdnval.Value).Selected = true;
                }
            }
        }

        protected void GridView1_RowUpdating(object sender, GridViewUpdateEventArgs e)
        {
            //GridView1.EditIndex = -1;           

            TextBox tb = (TextBox)GridView1.FindControl("txtUName1");// Not getting object *tb* in case of update

            if (tb != null)
            {
                string text = tb.Text;
            }          
        }

        public class Employee
        {
          public int Id { get; set; }
          public string Name1 { get; set; }
          public string Name2 { get; set; }
          public string Name3 { get; set; }
          public string Country { get; set; }            
        }

        private List<Employee> ReturnList()
        {
            DataTable dt = new DataTable();
            dt.Columns.AddRange(new DataColumn[3] { new DataColumn("Id"), new DataColumn("Name"), new DataColumn("Country") });
            dt.Rows.Add(1, "1,2,3", "United States");
            dt.Rows.Add(2, "", "India");
            dt.Rows.Add(3, "4,5,6", "France");
            dt.Rows.Add(4, "", "Russia");

            for (int i = 0; i < dt.Rows.Count; i++)
            {
                Employee emp = new Employee();
                emp.Id = Convert.ToInt32(dt.Rows[i]["Id"]);
                emp.Name1 = dt.Rows[i]["Name"].ToString();
                emp.Country = dt.Rows[i]["Country"].ToString();
                lstEmp.Add(emp);
            }

            return lstEmp;
        }
    }


}
```

Working on ASP.Net GridView after long time and I am stuck to find the text box object inside the GridView in EditItemTemplate. Googling this from the last few hours but not able to find the resolution of my problem.

Please help.

Comment: Never post all of your code here otherwise you will get no answer. just post the lines that cause error.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try to find textbox using below code

```
 GridViewRow row = TaskGridView.Rows[e.RowIndex];

TextBox tb = (TextBox)(row.Cells[0].Controls[0]);
```

OR

```
  TextBox tb = (TextBox)(row.FindControl("txtUName1"));
```

Hope this helps you